# Load photo in the gallery as bitmap object in Android

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-image

How can I load the images from the gallery as android Bitmap objects???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try in your Activity:

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
....
private void selectPicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
....
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    .........
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```